# GEE: Extracting country names from FAO dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine

The FAO GAUl dataset linked below has an 'ADM0_NAME' attribute, and I would like to see/ export these country names. However, I cannot print or export these names because I get an error.

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var names = countries.select('ADM0_NAME')
print(names)
```

I then get the following error:

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
User memory limit exceeded.
```

(https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/FAO_GAUL_2015_level0#table-schema)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following lines instead.

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var names = countries.aggregate_array('ADM0_NAME');

var keys = ee.Dictionary(names).keys();

print(keys);

var values = ee.Dictionary(names).values();

print(values.sort());
```

After running them in GEE code editor, you will get names of countries as follows (visualized only an extract of them in one of produced lists):

```
List (141 elements)
0: Aksai Chin
1: Algeria
2: American Samoa
3: Andorra
4: Antigua and Barbuda
5: Argentina
6: Australia
7: Austria
8: Azerbaijan
9: Azores Islands
10: Bahamas
11: Bangladesh
12: Bassas da India
13: Belarus
14: Belize
15: Bermuda
16: Bird Island
17: Bouvet Island
18: Brazil
19: British Virgin Islands
20: Brunei Darussalam
21: Burkina Faso
22: Burundi
23: Canada
24: Cape Verde
25: Central African Republic
26: Chile
.
.
.
```

You need to search why two lists. In the second list appear both 'Portugal' and 'Madeira Islands'. However, 'Madeira Islands' are Portuguese territory. Name as 'Canada' appears in both lists and 'United States of America' is repeated in second list.

**Editing Note:**

Following script allows obtain repeated and non repeated elements in second list and, finally, join both lists with distinct elements sorted by name.

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var names = countries.aggregate_array('ADM0_NAME');

var keys = ee.Dictionary(names).keys();

print("keys", keys);

var values = ee.Dictionary(names).values();

print("values", values.sort());

var repeatedBothLists = values.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(keys.contains(ele), ele, 0);
  
}).removeAll([0]);

print("repeated both lists", repeatedBothLists);

var diffSecondList = values.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(keys.contains(ele), 0, ele);
  
}).removeAll([0]);

print("differents in second list", diffSecondList.sort());

var joinTwoLists = keys.cat(diffSecondList);

print("two lists joined with different elements", joinTwoLists.distinct().sort());

var countries_list = ee.FeatureCollection(joinTwoLists 
  .map(function(element){ 
    return ee.Feature(null,{'country':element})}));

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(countries_list,
"countries_list", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"countries_list",  //file name
"CSV");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the table joining code provided! First tried to export the joinTwoLists variable, but I had to create a new featurecollection first and then export it:
var countries_list = ee.FeatureCollection(joinTwoLists
                        .map(function(element){
                        return ee.Feature(null,{prop:element})}))

Comment: You're welcome. I modified code in **Editing Note** for including that.

Comment: Manually testing for repeats is very inefficient.  You can simply use distinct.
    countries.distinct('ADM0_NAME').aggregate_array('ADM0_NAME').
And the results aren't dictionaries, so casting to ee.Dictionary does nothing in that code.